# Convergent sequences equal to limit, but also not equal to limit

Tags: real-analysis

Analysis question:

Give an example of, or show that there is no such example of a single convergent sequence *(An)* with limit *l* for which *An = l* for infinitely many values of *n*, and *An* does not equal *l* for infinitely many values of *n*.

I think its impossible, but dont know how to prove it.

Comment: $0,1/2,0,1/3,0,\cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

I would define $A_n$ differently for odd and even numbers like this:

$A_n = l$ for odd $n$
$A_n = l + \frac{1}{n}$ for even $n$